# Vectorize nested for loop in python to find curl

Tags: python-3.x, performance, for-loop, curl, vectorization

I am trying to find the curl of a 3D vector (with x,y,z components) which has values over a 3D grid of size (1200,1200,400). I was able to find curl using the finite difference method using nested for loops. But only for a section of the data. It's computation time is way higher for the entire set of (1200,1200,400) grid points. So, I tried using a package numba to speed up, but it didn't work. So, I tried vectorizing the whole thing. But the problem is there is something wrong (broadcasting error) with the way I am indexing the vector.

NB: I am relatively new to python

So, here is my approach:

1. create three 1D arrays x,y,z to represent the grid axis which can be used to index the vector
2. Put the arrays as indices of the vector. For eg: vx[x,y,z] I expect it to give the value of vx in the entire grid.

To find the curl I need to add and subtract 1 from the indices (when I use finite difference method). The error I get is

IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (1200,) (1200,) (400,)

I tried looking it up. tried changing the shape to (1200,1) instead of (1200,), error remained.

This is the function I defined:

```
def curl(rx,ry,rz):
    curlvx = (vz[rx,np.add(ry,1)%1200,rz] - vy[rx,np.add(ry,-1)%1200%1200,rz])/0.02 - (vy[rx,ry,np.add(rz,1)%400] - vy[rx,ry,np.add(rz,-1)%400])/0.02
    curlvy = (vx[rx,ry,np.add(rz,1)%400] - vx[rx,ry,np.add(rz,-1)%400])/0.02 - (vz[np.add(rx,1)%1200,ry,rz] - vz[np.add(rx,-1)%1200,ry,rz])/0.02
    curlvz = (vy[np.add(rx,1)%1200,ry,rz] - vy[np.add(rx,-1)%1200,ry,rz])/0.02 - (vx[rx,np.add(ry,1)%1200,rz] - vx[rx,np.add(ry,-1)%1200,rz])/0.02
    return [curlvx,curlvy,curlvz]
```

Where I call my function like this:

```
x=np.arange(0,1200)
y=np.arange(0,1200)
z=np.arange(0,400)
curl(x,y,z)
```

This is the line where I'm getting error.

```
curlvx = (vz[rx,np.add(ry,1)%1200,rz] - vy[rx,np.add(ry,-1)%1200%1200,rz])/0.02 - (vy[rx,ry,np.add(rz,1)%400] - vy[rx,ry,np.add(rz,-1)%400])/0.02
```

The is the part `vz[rx,np.add(ry,1)%1200,rz]` which is showing error

Comment: Try `vz[:, (ry + 1)%1200, :]`, and similar for the other slices

Comment: Thanks it worked! I was curious as to what python meant when it said broadcasting error. What difference does it make from using ':' to explicitly giving the array of indices. Thank you so much btw!